# Utilizing multiple python projects

Tags: python

I have a python app, that I'm developing. There is a need to use another library, that resides in different directory.

The file layout looks like this:
dir X has two project dirs:

- current-project
- xLibrary

I'd like to use xLibrary in currentProject. I've been trying writting code as if all the sources resided in the same directory and calling my projects main script with:

```
PYTHONPATH=.:../xLibrary ./current-project.py
```

but this does not work. I'd like to use its code base without installing the library globaly or copying it to my project's directory. Is it possible? Or if not, how should I deal with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a good programming practice to isolate packages into actual packages and treat them as such. If you're sure you'd like to continue with that approach though you can modify the search path from within python via:

```
import sys
sys.path.append( "<path_containing_the_other_python_files>" )
```

To avoid embedding absolute paths, you can use `os.path.abspath(__file__)` to obtain the absolute path to the currently executing .py file and follow up with a few `os.path.dirname()` calls to construct the proper relative path for inclusion to `sys.path`

A slightly altered approach that would allow you to get the best of both worlds would be to add an `__init__.py` file to `xLibrary`'s directory then add the path containing 'xLibrary' to `sys.path` instead. Subsequent Python code could then import everything "properly" via `from xLibrary import my_module` rather than just `import my_module` which could be confusing to people accustomed to the standard package directory layout.

Answer (score 2):

This depends how you use `xLibrary` from `current-project`.

If you do something like `from xLibrary import module1` inside `current-project`, the `xLibrary` needs to be laid out as a Python package:

```
xLibrary/
xLibrary/__init__.py
xLibrary/module1.py  # or whatever other modules the package consists of
```

In this case, you should include `xLibrary`'s parent directory in `PYTHONPATH`:

```
PYTHONPATH=.:.. ./current-project.py
```

However, if `xLibrary` is just a collection of Python modules that you import individually (that is, if you do `import module1` and `import module2` ìn `current-project`, with `xLibrary` containing the files `module1.py` and `module2.py`), you should include `xLibrary` in PYTHONPATH just as you did:

```
PYTHONPATH=.:../xLibrary ./current-project.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bash$ ln -s ../xLibrary xLibrary
```

Comment: Seems easiest but really is not :) I'd like to keep this quite generic, and platform independant :D

Answer (score 0):

First, it is probably better to use absolute paths in your PYTHONPATH variable.
Second, I don't think you need to add current directory to the path.

Other than that, it would be good to know what it is that doesn't work and what the error message is.
The command line you have there seems to be missing a semicolon
Try these two:

```
a=12 echo $a
b=12 ;echo $b
```

...and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Actually I need "." in PyTHOnPath due to some python quirks with handling UTF-8.

Comment: Ok, didn't know about that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other suggestions, you may consider the [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) package. After writing a little setup.py file you can "virtually install" the library and avoid all the PYTHONPATH munging in general.

This is a really good practice and is encouraged by the python community.

Otherwise I prefer the use of sys.path method (by Rakis)